# Does anyone know the real #SOreadytohelp T-shirt sizing?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

So I was lucky to win #SOreadytohelp T-shirt. That's great, however there is one caveat. I am really in the middle between typical S and M size, resulting in 50/50 chance of one of them being too small or too big.

Does anyone know the real sizes in cm or inch? Being lucky one time I would bet to get wrong size and have someone else wear it in the end as a result.

Comment: We may need [Clothing Stack Exchange](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/18036/swagoverflow-clothing) after all.

Comment: As an additional challenge, American S usually means European M or more. Knowing the actual sizes would really be helpful

Comment: I would order the size that will fit you once you reach your fitness goals. Are you aiming to slim? Then choose an S. Are you aiming to bulk? Choose an M. If you plan not to exercise/diet in the long-term choose the M, it will fit you soon enough.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### The unofficial guide to picking the right size of official SO Tee Shirt.

(This is specific to the charcoal heather, logo-only Stack Overflow tees.)

**Unisex/Men's (square, crew-neck) Cut:**

- If you always wear a given size, order that one.
- If you are *between* sizes, and ever vacillate depending on cut, **you want the smaller one.**

**Women's (fitted, scoop neck) Cut:**

- If you always wear a given size, order that one.
- If you are *between* sizes, and ever vacillate depending on cut, **you want the larger one.**

The sizes aren't way off the average, but the men's fit seems to be going for "a little loose" and the women's seems to be going for, "pretty fitted."

**Prefer to read the spec yourself?**

Here are links to the relevant SKUs for the blanks we currently use (as of 9/11/2015):

[Women's Tri-Blend Scoop Tee](https://store.districtclothing.com/ladies-tri-blend-scoop-tee-dm443-p209.aspx#noresults) (*District Made - Ladies* line)

[Men's Tri-Blend Crew Tee](https://store.districtclothing.com/tri-blend-crew-neck-tee-dt142-p65.aspx#noresults) (*District - Young Mens* line)

[image: official fit guide]
<sub>(source: [nexternal.com](https://cdn.nexternal.com/district/images/Fit_Guide.png))</sub>

Comment: Do we have a sizing chart from the manufacturer we can reference?

Comment: Oh, good thought, @BrianNickel. I'll add.

Comment: ugh, inches :-) Is there a SI chart which would be more meaningful for the remaining 90% of our users?

Comment: @sklivvz, sadly, you'll have to convert, as our vendor has  rejected your wacky metric system, with its "consistent, base-10" approach in favor of one based on the length of some dead king's nose.  :P

Answer (score 14):

Hang on a sec... I'm wearing one, let me find a tape measure...

This is a medium. Not too sure how to measure properly, so see pics below:
[image: Awesome T top pic]
[image: Awesome T full pic]

Click for full size pics.

Comment: I think they have a few different designs, but hopefully sizes are the same. Don't know about the SO ones, but an SU one is white (can't measure it as it's not to hand).

Comment: You say you are wearing the shirt but I don't see your neck there! Spooky 0_o

Comment: It is true, i'm an invisible very thin unicorn!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming what we're sending out is the exactly like the ones I have (which I assume, but you can wait for confirmation from someone who actually handles swag), a men's cut L is 74cm top-to-bottom (red line) and 58cm wide (cyan line) when the shirt (without anyone in it) is lying flat on the floor.

[image: picture of a tshirt with the measurement axes shown]

<sub>(T-Shirt image from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grey_Tshirt.jpg))</sub>

Comment: These are helpful measurements. Shoulder width would be a bit more useful. However, it does not help one deciding between S/M :-).

Comment: Ah sorry I misread, I had read "L and M".

Comment: @Fenikso You have an image.  With units.  Try counting pixels and dividing?

Comment: @Yakk care to elaborate on exact algorithm how to extrapolate the measurements and pixels to S and M size?

Comment: @Fenikso Well, you get shoulder width of L!  ;)  I just noticed that the above picture isn't actually the t-shirt, so you cannot even get the shoulder width from it.  Sigh.